# Wildcard (*) Searches With Thinking Sphinx

Tags: thinking-sphinx

Is it possible to give star (*) between the search text .
Example => peo*le

Answer (score 3):

The enable_star option allows prefix matching ('foo*') and infix matching ('*foo*'). It does not, however allow you to stick the * in the middle of a word as the question asks. The best simple solution I can suggest for the described case is searching as two words with 'any' matching:

```
IndexedThingie.search('peo le', :match_mode => :any)
```

If you specifically need 'all' style matching for everything else, you should look into the expression matching syntax in the Sphinx manual (http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/2.0.1/extended-syntax.html), which is available if you specify the 'extended' match mode (see TS match mode documentation: http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/searching.html#matchmodes). It might be complicated, but with some manipulation of your search input, you should be able to manage it. In particular, look at the 'strict order' operator, '<<'.

```
IndexedThingie.search('peo << le', :match_mode => :extended)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. `enable_star: 1` or `enable_star: true` in your sphinx.yml.